# rewrite rule if iphone?

Tags: iphone, apache, mod-rewrite

just need one url on my site to check if its a mobile device and then rerite the url accordingly.

want to rewrite;
http://2amfilms.co.ukl/play-reel/miranda-bowen/playpeaches-and-cream
to
http://2amfilms.co.ukl/**mobile**/play-reel/miranda-bowen/playpeaches-and-cream

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*iPhone.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^play-reel(.*)\$ mobile/play-reel$1 [R=302,NC]  

RewriteRule ^mobile/play-reel/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ play-reel-new-html5-02.php?director=$1&video=$2 [L]
# the 3rd line works but cant get the url to change for it to be picked up
```

can anyone see what's wrong? There's no erro

best, Dan

Comment: I think this questions will get much better answers on serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead this:

```
RewriteRule ^play-reel(.*)\$ mobile/play-reel$1 [R=302,NC]
```

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^play-reel(.*)$ mobile/play-reel$1 [R=302,NC]
```

Comment: that nearly does but transforms 1$ into the filename & quesries;/mobile/play-reel-new-html5-02.php?director=miranda-bowen&video=playpeaches-and-cream

Comment: let me clear this... you want user see that as /mobile/play-reel/miranda-bowen/playpeaches-and-cream but processed internally as /mobile/play-reel-new-html5-02.php?director=miranda-bowen&video=playpeaches-and-cream . Am I correct?

Comment: nearly! i want /mobile/play-reel/miranda-bowen/playpeaches-and-cream processed internally as there is rule ready to pick that up (3rd line). So i just need to transform the url if its an iphone before then...